# find/replacement pattern visual studio (omit the last matched character)

Tags: regex, visual-studio, replace

I have a `.cs` file with some odd variable names which i wanna replace theme with some more readable names using replacement tool (`CTRL`+`H`) in visual studio.

Consider i wanna replace every `abc=` or `abc=;` with `abc`.
The pattern i choose for replacement is:
    find:`(\w\w\w)=[\s;]`
    replace with: `$&`
Obviously it won't work, because `$&` replace all of matched characters in 'find' section. meanwhile, I want all matched characters expect `=` character at the end.

Comment: i dont know visual studio, but dont you just have to replace by `$1` = only your match group `(\w\w\w)`

Comment: @fallenhero exactly what i want. why not put it as answer? of course more robust answer would be `find:(\w\w\w)=([\s;])` replace:`$1$2` in my case